# AngularJS orderBy is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am using $http.jsonp to get some json data from a joomla website.

I am just pulling in categories, i.e.

```
{
id: "89",
name: "Labour",
description: "&lt;p&gt;{module Labour Featured Stories}&lt;/p&gt;",
image: "/media/k2/categories/",
language: "*",
parent: "87"
}

{
id: "90",
name: "International",
description: "&lt;p&gt;{module International Featured Stories}&lt;/p&gt;",
image: "/media/k2/categories/",
language: "*",
parent: "87"
}
```

I am trying to organise these categories by id using orderBy: | orderBy:'-id'"

This works but in a weird way, the output is: 1, 10, 100, 2, 23, 200, 3, 34, 300, etc..

which is obviously not correct.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: might be the issue is you are sorting string instead of number

Comment: @pankajparkar is correct. Everything is working as expected: its ordering by string comparison. You need to change your data so that the `id`s are numbers and not strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your response from the server side, as you are doing sorting on  array `-id` is doing ordering on basis of `string` comparison. Change that string to number(integer) will make more sense. Rather using filter and do converting it to integer then do the sorting, That wouldn't be considered as a good way.

**JSON**

```
{
  id: 89, //<-- this should be number instead of string
  name: "Labour",
  description: "&lt;p&gt;{module Labour Featured Stories}&lt;/p&gt;",
  image: "/media/k2/categories/",
  language: "*",
  parent: "87"
}

{
  id: 90, //<-- this should be number instead of string
  name: "International",
  description: "&lt;p&gt;{module International Featured Stories}&lt;/p&gt;",
  image: "/media/k2/categories/",
  language: "*",
  parent: "87"
}
```

Comment: Sorry i tried this but it is not working. Don't know where i am doing mistake.
Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRTYREV0sMkTTuLduQBH?p=preview

Comment: @BharatBhushan it seems correct you are using descending order using `-` sign which is showing correct result

Comment: I tried with both des and asc order both are giving same result